# String replace (w with x and y with z)

Tags: javascript

I'd basically like to do `replace(/ /g,"-")` and `replace(/'/g,"")` so a title Over 60's becomes a slug over-60s. Is this possible in one replace?

(`toLowerCase()` will be added right after the above)

Comment: Where does `title` and `slug` come into it? Should there be a replace for those too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a custom function as second parameter:

```
var txt = "Over 60's";

txt = txt.replace(/ |'/g, function(match){
    if (match === " "){
       return "-";
    }
    return "";
});

txt // Over-60s
```

see [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: My mistake, mis-read the options, have deleted the comments so as not to confuse others